# "Mount" a loopback device from SD card without root

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, mount, bind-mount

I'd like to move Termux/Nix-on-droid on my SD card as I lack space on internal storage. Unfortunately, SD cards are formatted in extFat so they can't deal with stuff that are common on ext4 systems, notably symlinks. I was thinking to use for that a `.img` file formatted in ext4 using `mkfs`, and mount it somewhere. But since my device is not rooted (and I don't want to root it for various reasons) I can't mount the file, even via adb:

```
/sdcard $ mount DCIM/virtualfs test_mount/                                                                                                                                                              
mount: bad /etc/fstab: No such file or directory
```

Is there any trick I can do to do that? For instance using some fakechroot-like tools?

Comment: Write access to the sdcard is on recent devices not possible using native Linux programs.  Apps have to use the MediaStore service using it's Java API. Therefore I don't think Termux will work on an sd-card without root permissions.

Comment: Ok too bad, thanks. I was hoping that it would be possible maybe to fake that by using `LD_PRELOAD` to replace the system calls when a file is read/written: for instance I think that some tools like fake-chroot exploits tricks like that.